JWT Authentication in multiple schemas
I am using the loopback4 starter repo to test a scenario where I manage my models (like FAQs, Pages, etc) in a separate datasource.
However, I can't seem to authenticate using JWT as it never triggers the return statement in of the value
import {Provider} from '@loopback/context';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {HttpErrors} from '@loopback/rest';
import {verify} from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {VerifyFunction} from 'loopback4-authentication';

import {RevokedTokenRepository} from '../repositories';
import {AuthenticateErrorKeys} from '../types/error-keys';
import {AuthUser} from '../models/auth-user.model';

export class BearerTokenVerifyProvider
  implements Provider<VerifyFunction.BearerFn>
{
  constructor(
    @repository(RevokedTokenRepository)
    public revokedTokenRepository: RevokedTokenRepository,
  ) {}

  value(): VerifyFunction.BearerFn {
    console.log('gets triggered');

    return async (token: string) => {
      console.log("doesn't get triggered");

      if (token && (await this.revokedTokenRepository.get(token))) {
        throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(AuthenticateErrorKeys.TokenRevoked);
      }
      const user = verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string, {
        issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
      }) as AuthUser;
      return user;
    };
  }
}

Within the Page controller, I have the following endpoint:
  @authenticate(STRATEGY.BEARER)
  @authorize({permissions: [PermissionKey.ViewPage]})
  @get('/pages', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Page model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'array', items: {'x-ts-type': Page}},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find(@param.filter(Page) filter?: Filter<Page>): Promise<{data:Page[], count: number}> {
    const count = await this.pageRepository.count(filter?.where);
    return {data: await this.pageRepository.find(filter), count:count.count};
  }

I ensured I have the proper permission (ViewPage). The endpoint works fine without authentication, but gives an NotAllowedAccess error with authentication.
If I do the same for my /roles endpoint (which exists in the same schema as user, auth-user, etc) I am able to successfully authenticate.
@authenticate(STRATEGY.BEARER)
  @authorize({permissions: [PermissionKey.ViewRole]})
  @get('/roles', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Array of Role model instances',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'array', items: {'x-ts-type': Role}},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async find(
    @param.query.object('filter', getFilterSchemaFor(Role))
    filter?: Filter<Role>,
  ): Promise<Role[]> {
    return this.roleRepository.find(filter);
  }

The only difference seems to be that the FAQ and Page model exist in a different schema.
How can I make this work?
